# Upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 but get message Oh no! Something has gone wrong

Tags: upgrade, boot-repair

Tried to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04 and got: Oh no Something has gone wrong  A problem has occurred and the system cant recover. Please logout and try again

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? Can you post a screenshot? Did you logout and try again?

Comment: Please read this info https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I suggest you to reinstall mutter  ( it is default desktop manager of Ubuntu. )